# Will/Does IE10 Support Touch Events?

Tags: events, dom, touch, internet-explorer-10

I'm looking at doing a project that would target Internet Explorer 10 using a touch screen.  I don't currently have a touch screen handy, but need to know if Internet Explorer 10 does or will support DOM touch events.

Answer (score 19):

**Update**: Touch Events are [*in development*](https://status.modern.ie/touchevents?term=touch) in Internet Explorer.

While IE10 will not support the *touchstart* and *touchend* type of events, it will support an arguably superior model consisting of Pointers. These generic pointers capture input from pens, mice, and fingers. A great primer was given in the post [*Touch Input for IE10 and Metro style Apps*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx), dated Sept, 2011.

You should be able to get the older *touch* model to work well with the MSPointer model with just abit of feature-detection and clever-scripting:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("#foo"),
    evt = window.navigator.msPointerEnabled ? "MSPointerDown" : "touchstart";

elm.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
```

More on Pointer and Gesture events can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh673557.aspx

**Important Developments**

- The [W3C has formed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/11/12/w3c-charters-pointer-events-working-group.aspx) a [Working Group](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/) based on Microsoft's Pointer model.
- [Hand.js: a polyfill for supporting pointer events on every browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx)

Comment: `MSPointerDown` has been deprecated as of IE11

Comment: @andreszs Can you give as a source for this information?

Comment: @SebastianBarth as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn304886(v=vs.85))  the MS prefix was first implemented because when IE10 was released, the W3C specification wasn't ready. When IE11 came out, the specification had reached _Candidate Recommendation_ status, and the MS vendor prefix versions have been deprecated in favor of the non-prefixed signatures. So you must use `PointerDown`, etc. since IE11.

Answer (score 6):

It appears IE 10 doesn't support the 'touchstart' family of events used by iOS and other mobile browsers.  IE 10 does however support multi-touch events using their own 'MSPointer' events.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh272903#_DOMTouch for details and example sites like http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/TouchEffects.

Comment: Just wanted to add: MSPointer is better than those touch events in the sense that it supports any type of pointer device. For example, pen + touch + mouse combination used at the same time is not a problem. It's in my opinion, far better implementation than iOS's touchstart, etc.

Comment: I agree with Tower that it may be smarter, but it make more work for people.

Comment: Touch, pen and mouse are three different interaction paradigms. Your finger does not work like a mouse. This isn't a superior solution, it's a muddy solution.

Comment: @Tower notice that the `MS` prefix has been [dropped since IE11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn304886(v=vs.85)) and now it works in all browsers without prefixes.