# how can I add swipe detection to a javascript script that uses keydown

Tags: javascript, media-player, hammer.js

I have a site that uses mediaboxAdv1.3.4b.js to display images. Keydown events are used to move through images and I would like to add the ability on a mobile device to use swipe left/right. In the MediaboxAdv code the relevant part seems to be that pasted below. I guess it should be straightforward to edit this to add swipe events using something like hammer.js but my experiments so far have failed.

```
    if (options.keyboard) document[fn]("keydown", keyDown);
}

function keyDown(event) {
        switch(event.code) {
            case 27:    // Esc
            case 88:    // 'x'
            case 67:    // 'c'
                close();
                break;
            case 37:    // Left arrow
            case 188:   // , <
            case 80:    // 'p'
                previous();
                break;
            case 39:    // Right arrow
            case 190:   // . >
            case 78:    // 'n'
                next();
        } 
    }
    if (options.stopKey) { return false; };
}

function previous() {
    return changeImage(prevImage);
}

function next() {
    return changeImage(nextImage);
```

Comment: Maybe this will help. [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events)

Comment: many thanks for the suggestion, but according to the page these touch events are not well supported outside firefox - and I must admit I am bit lost about how to use them anyway.

Comment: [hand.js](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx) looks like a good polyfill (found [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986490/will-does-ie10-support-touch-events)). I've also found a gist to wire up touch events based on browser support [here](https://gist.github.com/eklimcz/3783097)